# alternative to GdkDrawable in gtk+3

Tags: c, gtk3

GdkDrawable class that was present in gtk+2 is not in gtk+3. What is alternative to that?
I want to plot a graph using gtk+3 and C.

Comment: Wouldn't `GtkDrawingArea` be enough? I.e. draw to pixbuf and assign it to drawing area.

Comment: Check this [migration guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch24s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.7) to see how to do it... the replacement depends on what part of `GdkDrawable`'s functionality you need.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [GTK+3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch24s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.7), `GdkDrawable` is gone, and the alternative is to use a `cairo_surface_t` or a [GdkPixpuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/).